# CSS Wrapper not expanding when using "top" positioning

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the wrapper to expand with the content div, it works fine until I add some top positioning to the content div then the content div overflows from the wrapper

I have tried overflow auto on the wrapper which seems to work but adds unwanted scrollbars, and hidden just clips the end off the content div..... is there anyway to have the wrapper auto expand when using the TOP positioning method, maybe I need to add padding to the wrapper bottom to compensate? - though I would like to use the same wrapper id on multiple pages with different content heights

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #FC0;
}
#content {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: #F60;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="content">
    Content...
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly are you expecting? Do you want the orange BG to cover the whole of red thing?

Comment: Why are you using relative positioning for this? Clearly, it's not intended for what you are trying to achieve. Why not use margins and paddings?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: @Roope should I be using something like margin-top instead to position the content div?

Comment: Yes, for example. Check out Paulie's link.

Comment: Paulie_D, Roope, Andrew Axton - Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with position relative. Think of position relative as "freezing" the element's boundaries. If you modify the position it will not change the original bounding box but just change how it's displayed on the screen. So your wrapper is still thinking that the child element has a height of 300px, the top 200px doesn't register as height.

The easiest fix would be to add a margin-top instead of using top.

```
margin: 200px auto 0;
```